Ubuntu 24.04 bluetooth no bluetooth adapter found foxconn
Hi guys this is all my info, I have tried everything but still no luck on the bluetooth
ariel@ariel-Desktop-pc:~  $ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-12-09 15:45:55 -03; 23min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 4829 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 74205)
     Memory: 792.0K (peak: 1.4M)
        CPU: 13ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─4829 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Blueto>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: Starting SDP server
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() S>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_i>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() S>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() S>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() S>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() S>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() S>
Dec 09 15:45:55 ariel-Desktop-pc bluetoothd[4829]: Bluetooth management interfa>





ariel@ariel-Desktop-pc:~  $ \bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# 



ariel@ariel-Desktop-pc:~  $ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; hciconfig -a
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:1ace ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ROG OMNI RECEIVER
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0e2 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. Logi Bolt Receiver
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:1a52 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB Audio
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0b05:19af ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:35 acl:0 sco:0 events:5 errors:0
    TX bytes:253 acl:0 sco:0 commands:5 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 

ariel@ariel-Desktop-pc:~  $ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; hciconfig -a
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:1ace ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ROG OMNI RECEIVER
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0e2 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. Logi Bolt Receiver
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:1a52 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB Audio
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0b05:19af ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:35 acl:0 sco:0 events:5 errors:0
    TX bytes:253 acl:0 sco:0 commands:5 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 

ariel@ariel-Desktop-pc:~  $ sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; uname -r; mokutil --sb
[    4.179744] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount - Mount unit for firmware-updater, revision 127...
[    4.180128] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firmware\x2dupdater-147.mount - Mount unit for firmware-updater, revision 147...
[    4.359729] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.414301] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.414303] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.414308] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.414310] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.414313] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.503132] Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20241106163512
[    4.560487] mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20240219103337
[    4.642536] Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 1 expected 6
[    4.642538] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt func ctrl (-5)
[    4.642539] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[    5.358262] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x05000F00
[    5.358595] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.30 DEC: 3 VEP: 0 Revision: 4
[    5.358600] amdgpu 0000:13:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    5.492050] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.492054] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.492059] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   70.272462] Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20241106163512
[   70.278039] Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 6 expected 1
[   70.278043] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt patch dwnld (-5)
[   70.278051] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set up firmware (-5)
[   70.278052] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[  105.404150] Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20241106163512
[  105.544334] Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 1 expected 6
[  105.544343] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt func ctrl (-5)
[  105.544345] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[  137.386807] Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20241106163512
[  137.392525] Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 6 expected 1
[  137.392529] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt patch dwnld (-5)
[  137.392537] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set up firmware (-5)
[  137.392539] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[  140.917882] Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20241106163512
[  141.046606] Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 1 expected 6
[  141.046615] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt func ctrl (-5)
[  141.046617] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[  260.785197] Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20241106163512
[  260.790519] Bluetooth: hci0: Wrong op received 6 expected 1
[  260.790528] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt patch dwnld (-5)
[  260.790544] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set up firmware (-5)
[  260.790545] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[  284.284332] audit: type=1400 audit(1733770152.101:226): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" name="/proc/5487/maps" pid=5487 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  284.337743] audit: type=1400 audit(1733770152.154:229): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" name="/proc/5544/maps" pid=5544 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  284.619495] audit: type=1400 audit(1733770152.436:230): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-updater-app" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=5526 comm="firmware-update" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  284.619552] audit: type=1400 audit(1733770152.436:231): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-updater-app" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=5526 comm="firmware-update" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  284.619574] audit: type=1400 audit(1733770152.436:232): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-updater-app" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=5526 comm="firmware-update" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  284.619616] audit: type=1400 audit(1733770152.436:233): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-updater-app" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=5526 comm="firmware-update" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  782.056621] audit: type=1107 audit(1733770649.925:245): pid=1510 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=8298 label="snap.slack.slack" peer_pid=4829 peer_label="unconfined"
6.8.0-50-generic
SecureBoot disabled


Crazy but unpluggin the computer for about 10 minutes, fixed the issue, dont ask me how (
